# Python Scapy loop through pcap file with 1 second iteration

Tags: python, loops, scapy

I am going though a .pcap file using scapy. The code I am using gets the start time and end time using the first and last packet in the file. I would like to go trhough the file and for each second and extract some information. I am having trouble witht the loop, I am able to go though the first second but I cannot go though the second, third etc until the file ends.

I was incrementing timeFirst at the end of the second IF loop but it is not working.

Thanks, Here is the Code I am using.

```html
for pkt in data:
    counter += 1
    packetTime.append(pkt.time)

timeFirst = float(packetTime[0])
timeLast = float(packetTime[counter-1])

for pkt in data[DNS]:
    if pkt.time <= timeLast:
        if pkt.time >= timeFirst and pkt.time < timeFirst+1:
             if pkt.qr == 0:
                 zeroFreq += 1
             elif pkt.qr == 1:
                 oneFreq += 1
```

Working Code with 1 second Iteration

```html
for pkt in data:
    counter += 1
    packetTime.append(pkt.time)

timeFirst = float(packetTime[0])
timeLast = float(packetTime[counter-1])
timeLoop = timeFirst
timeLoop += 1

for pkt in data[DNS]:
    if pkt.time >= timeFirst and pkt.time < timeLoop:
        if pkt.qr == 0:
            zeroFreq += 1
        elif pkt.qr == 1:
            oneFreq += 1
    elif pkt.time >= timeLoop:
        timeLoop += 1
        zeroList.append(zeroFreq)
        oneList.append(oneFreq)
        zeroFreq = 0
        oneFreq = 0
        countSecond += 1
        timeList.append(countSecond)
```

The extra code counts the number of DNS requests and responses and adds them to a List.

Comment: unrelated but you can use a single if instead of nesting   `if timeFirst <= pkt.time <= timeLast < timeFirst+1:`, what do you mean by the second *if loop*?

Comment: Thanks I did not know about that. I mean this one if pkt.time >= timeFirst and pkt.time < timeFirst+1:

Comment: timeFirst+1 does not actually increment it just keeps adding  1 to the original value. You will need to  `timeFirst += 1` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have put some thought it into it and finally solved it. I will post the new code.

Comment: no worries, again you can simplify the expression `if timeFirst <= pkt.time < timeLoop`

Comment: Thanks, once I tidy up the code I will look into that.